# Given that $f(x^2+x+1)=f(x^2-x+1)$ for all $x$, is $f(x)$ periodic?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

> Given that $f(x)$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying
>   $$f(x^2+x+1)=f(x^2-x+1)\;\;\; \forall\;\;\;x\in\mathbb{R}$$ Is $f(x)$
>   periodic?

**My Attempt:**

$$f((x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4})=f((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4})$$

Let $x-\frac{1}{2}=t$

$$f((t+1)^2+\frac{3}{4})=f(t^2+\frac{3}{4})$$

Let $g(t)$ be a polynomial defined as
$$g(t)=t^2+\frac{3}{4}$$

Can I conclude anything from this?

Comment: The given condition has something to do with values of the function for arguments $\ge 3/4$. So we can give an example, $f=0$, and a counterexample, $f=0$ on $[3/4,\infty)$ and $f=-1$ on the rest...

Comment: @dan_fulea Why not making your counterexample an answer?

Comment: You need some very strong condition to guarantee that $f$ be periodic.  Even smoothness is not sufficiently strong (you can smoothly modify $f$ at any point in the interval $\left(-\infty,\frac34\right)$).  If you on the other hand know that $f$ is analytic, then you know for sure that it is periodic.

Comment: @Batominovski Why do we know the periodicity if we assume $f$ to be analytic?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If $f$ is continuous and periodic on $[a,\infty)$ with period $T$, then we can write $f(x)=A\,\sin\big(g(x)\big)+B$ with $x\geq a$ for some constants $A$ and $B$ and for some continuous function $g:[a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$.  If $f$ is in addition analytic, then $g$ is also analytic on $[a,\infty)$.  We then extend $g$ to the whole $\mathbb{R}$ using the relation $g(x)=g(\tilde{x})+2\pi nm$ if $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and and $\tilde{x}\in[a,a+T)$ are such that $g(a+T)=g(a)+2\pi n$ and  $x=\tilde{x}+Tm$ to obtain an analytic continuation $\tilde{g}$ of $g$ (which is unique).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven (Continued) Therefore, the analytic function $\tilde{f}$ defined by $\tilde{f}(x):=A\,\sin\big(\tilde{g}(x)\big)+B$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is periodic and agrees with $f$ on a subset $[a,\infty)$ of $\mathbb{R}$.  Thus, by the Identity Theorem for Analytic Functions, $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ must equal, being both analytic functions.  This means $f$ is periodic.

Comment: After thinking carefully, I am wrong.  There is no reason why $f$ should be periodic on $\left[\frac34,\infty\right)$ (I assumed this by mistake).  We only know that $f\circ g$ is periodic on the entire $\mathbb{R}$, where $g(x):=x^2+\frac34$.  So, my comments above are irrelevant, but they may be helpful in some way.

Answer (score 1):

$$f((t+1)^2+\frac{3}{4})=f(t^2+\frac{3}{4})$$

Definition of  a  periodic function $f(x+a)=f(x)$

As you can see in your equation $a$ is 1

or you can do it like this $$f(x^2+x+1)=f(x^2-x+1)\;\;\; \forall\;\;\;x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Now put $x+1$ in the second equation in place of $x$  they both become equal which means

$$g(x+1)=g(x)$$ Thus  period of your function $g(x)=f(x^2-x+1) $ is 1

Comment: Your first argument shows that $f\circ g$ 1-periodic, not that $f$ is. I also don't understand the second argument.

Comment: If $g(x)=f(x^2-x+1)$, then yes, $g$ is... But where does $f(x+1)=f(x)$ come from?

Comment: oh yeah my bad will edit it